# npx @capacitor/cli resolving to c:\windows\rstcli.exe

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a weird issue, when I try to run this `npx @capacitor/cli`. It somehow gets redirected to `rstcli.exe -I  1>Gcli.txt`. `rstcli.exe` is on `c:\windows\rstcli.exe`

I already uninstalled Intel Rapid Technology software (what is related to `rstcli.exe`) and manually deleted the exe file. But it still try to run it (but of course it fails)

> 'rstcli.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Does anyone knows how can I debug this problem?

I already discarted that as a [package problem](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4115).

And I already uninstalled and reinstalled node/npm (deleting all temp folders).

Edit: `where npx` returns:

```
where npx
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npx
```

It does not happens with other packages.

Comment: What is the output of `where npx` (if using Command Prompt) or `Get-Command npx` (if using PowerShell)?

Comment: Hi @DanielB I have add it to my post, it is on `c:\program files\nodejs\npx`

Comment: Do you perhaps have a file `C:\Windows\cli.bat`? If yes, what does it do?

Comment: Oh! that has `rstcli.exe -I >Gcli.txt` exactly what my problem is calling. Can you please write an answer to I can select it @DanielB ? Thanks!

Comment: It’s not an answer until we figure out how exactly `npx` ends up calling it. Because it really shouldn’t. // Okay, I think this is a bug in `npx`. You can also do `npx @whatever/notepad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `npx` has some seldom-used behavior: It prefers to run whatever it finds in `$PATH`. How it arrives at the decision to try `cli` when the input is `@capacitor/cli` I was not able to find out. Seems like a haphazard guess to me that may have been valid before scopes were a thing but not today.

In your case, you had a batch script in `$PATH` that happened to get in the way: `C:\Windows\cli.bat`. Apparently part of some Intel Rapid Storage Technology stuff. It is what contained your mystery command.

To make `npx` not do this, invoke it as follows:

```
npx --ignore-existing @capacitor/cli
```

---

In NPM 7, `npx` will be replaced by `npm exec` (or rather an alias to `npm exec`) which may have less surprising behavior.